# How do I make a batch file start at the top when run?

Tags: batch-file, command-line-interface

I've created a batch file, but when I run it and it loads, it goes down to where the user input is, cutting off part of my program.

Is there any way to make it start at the top and make the user have to manually scroll it down to look at what he's entering in?

Comment: I don't understand this question - do you want to show the source code of your program to your user? Or do you want to show some kind of text  (e.g. a license agreement), and the user should have to start reading from the beginning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you generate a lot of text to the console (more than one page worth) and then ask the user a question, like:

```
type bighonkintextfile
set /p answer=Yes?
```

I see only one *quick* solution. *Don't* just generate all that output. Pass it through a pager of some sort, something like:

```
type bighonkintextfile | more
set /p answer=Yes?
```

Then the user will be able to read it from the top and once `more` exits, the user will be asked for a response.

If you want something more robust or pretty-looking, I'd be looking at doing that with a well-crafted executable rather than a batch file.